# Sorted a tuple by value use a List when the value is equal

Tags: python, list, tuples, sorting

I have a list:

```
test1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
```

And a list of tuples:

```
test2 = [("c",1),("g",1),("b",1),("e",1),("g",1),("d",10),("a",10)]
```

I need sorted the:

```
[val for (key, val) in test2]
```

and when the `val` is equal the same `val`'s sorted by the `test1`:

```
test3 = [("b",1),("c",1),("e",1),("f",1),("g",1),("a",10),("d",10)]
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What is it working and what isn't ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) accepts an optional parameter `key`. The return value of the function (each item is passed to the function) is used instead of the items themselves.

```
>>> test1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
>>> test2 = [("c",1),("g",1),("b",1),("e",1),("g",1),("d",10),("a",10)]
>>> sorted(test2, key=lambda x: (x[1], test1.index(x[0])))
[('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('e', 1), ('g', 1), ('g', 1), ('a', 10), ('d', 10)]
```

Given the above key function order will be by the number first, then position in the `test1`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dict` mapping  each string in test1 to its index so for ties you sort by the index and the lookup is `0(1)`:

```
test1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
inds = dict(zip(test1, range(len(test1))))

test2 = [("c",1),("g",1),("b",1),("e",1),("g",1),("d",10),("a",10)]


print(sorted(test2,key=lambda x: (x[1], inds[x[0]])))
```

Output:

```
[('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('e', 1), ('g', 1), ('g', 1), ('a', 10), ('d', 10)]
```

If you actually wanted the strings to be in sorted order you could just use the string itself, using `itemgetter` instead of a lambda:

```
test2 = [("c", 1), ("g", 1), ("b", 1), ("e", 1), ("g", 1), ("d", 10), ("a", 10)]
from operator import itemgetter

print(sorted(test2, key=itemgetter(1, 0)))
[('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('e', 1), ('g', 1), ('g', 1), ('a', 10), ('d', 10)]
```

Comment: Is `itemgetter` faster than `lambda` ?

Comment: @IronFist, yep, itemgetter happens as the c level